# readFile function writes data

Tags: node.js

I've noticed that when running the following code:

```
fs.readdir('_DIRECTORY_WITH_THOUSANDS_OF_FILES_', function(e, f) {
        console.log(f.length);
        var _f = function() {
                if(f.length > 0) {
                    f.pop();
                    fs.readFile('_DIRECTORY_WITH_THOUSANDS_OF_FILES_/' + f.pop(), { encoding:'UTF-8' }, function(_e, _d) {
                            setImmediate(_f);
                        });
                }
            };
        setImmediate(_f);
    });
```

... the Disk Usage tab of the Activity Monitor app on my OS X machine displays the following:

[image]

And throughout the execution of the program, the `Bytes Written` value just keeps growing.

Does anyone know what is going on? I'm running with plenty of memory and swap is not being used.

Also, why are there apparently no bytes being read? Are the field values swapped or something?